# Django form validation on clicking Next instead of Submit

Tags: python, html, django

I have this HTML page in which I have 2 forms. Django is not checking the form validation for the first form. I want it to check form validation for the first form.
This is the Html Code

```
<form method="post" id="msform">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
      <li class="active" id="conf"><strong>Configuration</strong></li>
        <li id="auth"><strong>Authentication</strong></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div> <br> <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-card">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7">
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Cluster Configuration</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <h2 class="steps">Step 1 - 2</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{ form1|crispy }}
        </div> <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-card">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7">
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Authentication</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <h2 class="steps">Step 2 - 2</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{ form2|crispy }}
        </div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Next</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

If I use submit button instead of next for the first form then neither the second form opens nor the form is submitted (i.e. nothing is happening).

Answer (score 1):

So I think the issue might be because you have over arching form tag, and two forms sent inside it from your view function:

What you have right now is this:

```
<form>
<fieldset>
    <! –– Your Code ––>
        {{ form1|crispy }}
    </div> <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <! –– Your Code ––>
     {{ form2|crispy }}
    </div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Next</button>
</fieldset>

</form>
```

As you can see from the above simplification of your original post, you have two forms templated inside one form tag. Thus when you hit either of the the submit button both of them gets sent.

If I am not mistaken, I believe what you might want is something along the lines of this:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1">
<fieldset>
    <! –– Your Code ––>
        {{ form1|crispy }}
    </div> <input type="button" name="form1" class="next action-button" value="Next1" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<form name="form2" id="form2">
<fieldset>
    <! –– Your Code ––>
        {{ form1|crispy }}
    </div> <input type="button" name="form2" class="next action-button" value="Next2" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Take note of the fact that I have changed your button names, as well as added ids and names to each form, you might also want to add ids as well as unique values to your buttons as well. This would help you build if conditions to determine which form has been submitted and so on, in your view function

Here is a [link](https://www.codementor.io/@lakshminp/handling-multiple-forms-on-the-same-page-in-django-fv89t2s3j) that describe how to handle this in more depth.

Which is all nice and dandy, but the conclusion of that linked page is this:

[image]

Let me know if it helps, feel free to ask more if you do not understand/the changes does not work